# jQuery addClass to child elements only

Tags: jquery

The following code works:

```
jQuery(".left-content").find("li").hover(function () {
    jQuery(".left-content").find(".stamp").addClass('stamp-hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    jQuery(".left-content").find(".stamp").removeClass('stamp-hover');
  }
);
```

However, I have about 5 divs set up the same way on the page and when hovering over the li within say div 1, the class is added to all `div.stamp`'s within `div.left-content`'s on the page. Where I would like for the class to only be added to the `div.stamp` within the parent `div.left-content`.

```
<div class="left-content">
    <div class="content-section">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="stamp-anchor-wrapper">
        <div class="stamp"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply target the current element using `this`

```
jQuery(".left-content").find("li").hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).parents(".left-content").find(".stamp").addClass('stamp-hover');
  }, 
  function () {
    jQuery(this).parents(".left-content").find(".stamp").removeClass('stamp-hover');
  });
```